# OpenCV многопоточный поиск в видео

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, многопоточность, opencv

Написал программу на Qt с использованием OpenCV под Ubuntu которая ищет положение в видео файле по фото с экрана, к примеру.
Задается путь к видео, путь к изображению после обработки выдается время в секундах.

Решил оптимизировать добавив разбиение поиска на доступные ядра процессора.
Каждый поток выбирает ядро, инициализирует свой VideoCapture, начинает поиск с определенной позиции и на определенное количество кадров.
Все работает правильно, в моем случае все 12 ядер загружаются на сто процентов в отличии от первой версии которая загружала одно ядро.

НО!... Поиск идет примерно в 10 раз медленнее...

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Например потому что потоки ждут завершения работы друг друга и продолжают в каких-то бесконечный циклах молотить код, пока один из них чего-нибудь не найдет. Ну, как вариант )

Answer (score 0):

Например, узким местом может быть чтение файла. То есть 12 потоков ломятся одновременно читать что-то с диска, там это всё дело перегружает дисковый ввод-вывод и т.д.

Сразу много всего можно улучшить: если файл не очень большой, его можно мапить в память; в идеале хорошо бы, чтобы читал один VideoCapture (это достаточно быстро) и раздавал кадры потокам на обработку, т.е. придумать свою версию consumer-producer. Опять же, что там именно с потоками и как должно быть написано -- это отдельный, очень общий вопрос.
Ну и само чтение кадров как ускорять -- вторая проблема получается.